# How to create custom date display format that displays event duration

Tags: datetime

I am new to Drupal. I want to display event date like,

`"28/07/2016 | 02 PM to 04 PM"`

Default date formats display date like,

`"28/07/2016 - 02 PM to 28/07/2016 - 04 PM"`

How can I create such custom display format?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375674/how-can-a-custom-drupal-date-format-be-added\

Comment: Do you mean you are using 2 date fields for saving the start and end time?

Comment: yes @JimmyKo . I am using one field for date and 2 fields for start and end time respectively. I want it to be displayed it as One date value and two time values showing start and end time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Date and Time
2. There you will see a tab for format.
3. Create a new format string "Y-M-d".
4. Make this as your default for all date fields and you won't see the seconds any more.
5. You don't need the date module for basic formatting.

**UPDATE: From following comment,**

If you want optional End time, use [Timefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/timefield) module

> Timefield is a Field API field for storing simple non-timezone time
>   values, with an optional end time, utilizing a simple JQuery
>   timepicker widget for input.

Comment: Thank you for response @Arun. I don't want date to be displayed like Y-M-d or anything like that. I want to display date in the form of d-M-Y | start time - end time for example "28/07/2016 | 03 PM to 05 PM". Creating a new date format allows me to change order of date, month and year. How can I display time slots without repetition of date

Comment: Did you try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/timefield. This module will allow you to define time with  End time.

Comment: Issue got fixed?

Comment: Yes @Arun. I used one field for date and this time field module took care of time duration. So, I got what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `hook_date_formats()` you can create date format

**Example:**

```
function app_common_date_formats() {
  $formats = array();
  $formats[] = array(
    'type'    => 'test_custom_date_format',
    'format'  => 'd-M-Y',
    'locales' => array(), );
  foreach ($formats as $format) {
    variable_set('date_format_' . $format['type'], $format['format']);
  }
return $formats;
```

}

Comment: Hi @Fawwad, Thank you for response. I got your point, this code will create a date format in the form of d-M-Y.How can I get display format like "d-M-Y | 02 PM to 04 PM"?